# ActiveRecord: Chaining from another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a tagging system of Tags and tasks (tag has many tasks through TagTask, and vice-versa)

What I'd like to do is create a scope that returns all tasks that are in ALL of the tags provides. So, in the Tag model, it looks like this:

```
def self.combined_tasks(tag_ids)
    tasks = []
    tag_ids.each do |tag_id|
      tasks << self.find(tag_id).tasks
    end

    tasks.inject { |result, elem| result & elem }
end
```

The difficulty is, I can't think of any chainable way to create a scope within the Task model to do this efficiently. Palming it off to the Tag model via

```
def self.in_all_tags(tags_ids)
  tags = Tag.combined_tasks(tag_ids)
end
```

works, but understandably it doesn't seem to be chainable to other scopes.

Any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Task.joins(:tag_tasks).where(tag_tasks: {tag_id: tag_ids}).uniq
```